# Checkout a file from svn and append its timestamp to its name

Tags: bash, subversion

Suppose I have a file in SVN at

```
http://example.com/file.txt
```

I want to check it out to `file-20131218-2000.txt` where December 18, 2013 at 8pm is when the most recent commit to that file happened according to `svn log`.

What's a good way to do this in the bash shell?

```
$ uname -a
Linux my-computer 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My SVN version is 1.6.17.

Comment: Could you let us know what platform you are using, please? Just type `uname -a` - then edit your question with this info.

Comment: What version of SVN are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have a solution that is a bit of hackery.  Add the following function to your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
svnco() {
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then    # Fixed space here.
        echo "Usage: svnco [URL]"
        return
    fi

    DIRECTORY=`dirname "$1"`
    BASENAME=`basename "$1"`
    EXTENSION="${BASENAME##*.}"
    FILENAME="${BASENAME%.*}"
    DATE=$(date -d "`svn info "$1" | grep "Last Changed Date" | sed 's/Last Changed Date: //'`" +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
    svn co "$DIRECTORY" . --depth empty
    svn up "$BASENAME"
    mv "$BASENAME" "$FILENAME-$DATE.$EXTENSION"
}
```

This will give you the desired effect.  Once saved into your `.bashrc` you need to run `source ~/.bash_profile`

And to invoke, just do the following: `svnco http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/build.xml`

Fair warning, you might run into a problem eventually since this will also create a `.svn` directory as well. You can pop in a `rm -rf .svn` to the end of the function if you wish. I am not going to though.

Comment: instead of `grep` and `sed`: just ask for the date:
`svn info --show-item last-changed-date`

Answer (score 1):

When you do an `svn export`, `svn` sets the modification time of the exported file to the date of the revision.

So (`zsh` syntax):

```
zmodload zsh/stat
url=http://example.com/file.txt
svn export $url tmpfile &&
  zstat -F %Y%m%d-%H%M -A t +mtime tmpfile &&
  mv -- tmpfile $url:t:r.$t.$url:e
```

That one doesn't have a race condition where a new revision may have been checked in in between a `svn info` and `svn cat`.

If it has to be `bash`, assuming you have GNU `find`:

```
url=http://example.com/file.txt
svn export "$url" tmpfile &&
  t=$(find tmpfile -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td-%TH%TM') &&
  b=${URL##*/} &&
  mv -- tmpfile "${b%.*}.$t.${b##*.}"
```

If you want to do that for all the files there, then you can `export` the whole directory:

```
svn export http://example.com/ mydir
```

And do all the renames at once:

```
find mydir ! -type d -printf '%TY%Tm%Td-%TH%TM/%p\0' |
  while IFS=/ read -rd '' t f; do
    b=${f##*/}
    mv -Tv "$f" "${f%/*}/${b%.*}.$t.${b##*.}"
  done
```

(assuming GNU `find` and GNU `mv`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) to obtain information about a file in a remote repository, this doesn't require any checkout. You can use [`svn cat`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.cat.html) to retrieve a remote file to standard output, this also doesn't require any checkout.

```
date=$(LC_ALL=C svn info "$url" |
       awk 'sub(/^Last Changed Date: /, "") {gsub(/[-:]/, ""); print $1 "-" $2}')
basename=${url##*/}
extension=${filename##*.}; basename=${basename%".$extension"}
svn cat "$url" >"$basename-$date.$extension"
```